# Jenkins - FileName Extensions error

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins for my work where I am trying to JMeter through Jenkins build option to run a batch file, but blocked with the below error.

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace D:\
[] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson4481668363865698547.bat
The filename or extension is too long
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "D:\"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:243)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:212)
        at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
        at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
        at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:95)
        at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:64)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tried different option of invoking the build but always getting the same error.

Request you to please help in this issue, as I am not able to proceed.